# Table rewrite by last in lua

Tags: lua, url-rewriting, lua-table

I have a problem that I cannot solve.

If I execute the function 2 or 3 time whit this:

```
Core:CreateButton({ Name = "Spell__Slot", Slot = 1, OffSetY = 0, OffSetX = 0, }) Core:CreateButton({ Name = "Item__Slot", Slot = 2, OffSetY = 50, OffSetX = 0, }) Core:CreateButton({ Name = "Mount__Slot", Slot = 3, OffSetY = 0, OffSetX = 50, }) Core:CreateButton({ Name = "Pet__Slot", Slot = 4, OffSetY = 50, OffSetX = 50, })
```

all table "SavedData" is rewrite by the last:

[image: http://i64.tinypic.com/35hegib.jpg]

```
function Core:CreateButton(Saved)
-- Usage.
if type(Saved) ~= 'table' and type(Saved.Name) ~= 'string' and type(Saved.Slot) ~= 'number' then
    print("Core:CreateButton({Saved}): Button must have a valid Name[string] and Slot[number].")
    return
end
-- Create Table.
if not self.Region then self.Region = {} end
if not self.Region[Saved.Slot] then
    -- Unique Table.
    self.Region[Saved.Slot] = {}
    self.Region[Saved.Slot].Data = {}
    self.Region[Saved.Slot].Region = {}
    self.Region[Saved.Slot].SavedData = DefaultValue
    -- Table Merge.
    for key, value in pairs(Saved) do
        self.Region[Saved.Slot].SavedData[key] = value
    end
end end
```

Comment: `or` should be used here instead of `and`: `if type(Saved) ~= 'table' and type(Saved.Name) ~= 'string' and type(Saved.Slot) ~= 'number' then`

Comment: All your `SavedData` fields contain reference to the same table `DefaultValue`.  You must create new table every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
   self.Region[Saved.Slot].SavedData = DefaultValue
   -- Table Merge.
   for key, value in pairs(Saved) do
       self.Region[Saved.Slot].SavedData[key] = value
   end
```

with

```
   self.Region[Saved.Slot].SavedData = {}
   -- Table Merge.
   for key, value in pairs(DefaultValue) do
       self.Region[Saved.Slot].SavedData[key] = value
   end
   -- Table Merge.
   for key, value in pairs(Saved) do
       self.Region[Saved.Slot].SavedData[key] = value
   end
```